# Import statements: with or without React?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

There's a little bit of a debate at work on whether it is necessary to import `React` in stateless components and I can't find any docs about it. So:

```
//OPTION 1
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

//OPTION 2
import { PropTypes } from 'react';

export const Button = ({ action }) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={action}>Submit</button>
  );
}

Button.propTypes = {
  action: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

Some people say Option 1 is the best practice when using JSX; some other think component will fail with Option 2.

I have tried both and I can't see any difference, the component still works in both cases.

Option 1 or Option 2: which one is correct?

Comment: I get reference errors for option 2, so always use option 1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use option 1 because babel will transform your jsx
`<button onClick={action}>Submit</button>`
to
`React.createElement("button", { onClick: action }, "Submit");`

So as you see react must be in scope. You have two options:

1. import React from 'react';
2. or define React globally

Answer (score 9):

It depends on how you're building your files. If you're using a module bundler like webpack and there's no notion of a global React module then leaving out React will throw the error `React is not defined`.

This is because this:

```
let C = <div />
```

turns into:

```
let C = React.createElement("div", null)
```

So inside that particular module.. `React` is not imported and therefore will trip on the undefined variable.

You can expose `React` to the window namespace, then you don't need to import it into every file. That's up to you.

Comment: This makes sense. However I do use webpack and the component doesn't throw :confused:

Comment: Are you actually using the component somewhere? or just defining it.

Comment: I have `window.React = React;` in my `index.js` though, so I think you're right

Comment: Thanks for your input. I don't think it's quite right to say the problem is in the bundler though. The bundler in itself doesn't do any transpiling; but Babel does and there lies the issue.

Comment: it's about both. If there was no module bundler then you wouldn't be importing stuff at all. Also webpack has plugins for defining global modules which takes care of your problem. Of course it is about transpilation as well.