# Do we need to import React or just {Component, PropTypes} will do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

in all of my components I am currently including react like this:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react'
```

I don't see why everyone is including React when it is not used, hence wanted to check if it is safe to remove it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import statements: with or without React?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993680/import-statements-with-or-without-react)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is needed for JSX to work.

What the JSX processor does, essentially, is turn this:

```
<div />
```

into this:

```
React.createElement('div')
```

There are ways to tell it to use a different function, like `createElement` and then instead of `React` always import `{createElement}` — which is the *opposite* of an improvement, and you shouldn't do it anyway.