# Need to import prop types in React?

Tags: reactjs

Say I have a class and at the end I want to make it explicit in my code that it has no props so I add this at the bottom:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
};
```

Do I still need to import proptypes in this case using `import PropTypes from 'prop-types'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to since you aren't declaring any prop with it's PropType.

with `MyComponent.propTypes = {};` you are only declaring a property of MyComponent. You will need yo import PropTypes if you declare some prop with its own type.

`MyComponent.propTypes = { prop1: PropTypes.number}`

Comment: Ok. I was just worried because sometimes even if you don't use the exact name you used to import, it's still used once the code gets transpiled. i.e. `React` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206646/do-we-need-to-import-react-or-just-component-proptypes-will-do

Comment: Yo don't need to import PropTypes if you're not using it. There are libraries that need to be imported even if you explicitly don't use them. React for example, you need to import it as JSX needs react to work.
PropTypes does not need to be imported in this case.