# Testing React Components: How does it work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

In the jest docs, I found this simple example of testing react components:

```
// Link.react.test.js
import React from 'react';
import Link from '../Link.react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

test('Link changes the class when hovered', () => {
  const component = renderer.create(
    <Link page="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</Link>,
  );
  let tree = component.toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();

  // manually trigger the callback
  tree.props.onMouseEnter();
  // re-rendering
  tree = component.toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();

  // manually trigger the callback
  tree.props.onMouseLeave();
  // re-rendering
  tree = component.toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Why do we have to import `React` and `react-test-renderer`, but not have to import other test specific things, like `test`, `expect`?

Can someone explain, how this works under the hood and what actually happens when the tests are run?

Comment: `renderer.create` is used directly in the example right?

Comment: Oh, you are right! I updated the question. Thx.

Comment: Why you need to import React is answered here already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206646/do-we-need-to-import-react-or-just-component-proptypes-will-do and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993680/import-statements-with-or-without-react

Answer (score 1):

<del>It finds the binary `jest` and executes it with your script, this binary would compile your code first then run it, so those modules for testing would be imported during compiling time when those function keyword was found. You install Jest to your original application to test component. `React` module or others it really your stuff.</del>

**Update**

By tracing the repository of Jest 
[jest/packages/jest-runtime/src/script_transformer.js](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/69c11a0c8192e643f4aa4c0aa79ce09cdd1ab155/packages/jest-runtime/src/script_transformer.js), We could found out it utilize Node.js module [VM](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_class_vm_script) to run the script, and it has some method like `vm.createContext()` and `vm.Script().runInContext()`, so those internal module should be imported to sandbox programmatically.

Example from [VM](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_createcontext_sandbox_options)

```
const vm = require('vm');
const sandbox = { globalVar: 1 };            // <=> import expect, test 
vm.createContext(sandbox);
...
vm.runInContext('globalVar *= 2;', sandbox); // <=> Our test code.
```

So those module such as `expect`, and `test` may be imported like what `vm.createContext()` does above.

It's hard to exactly know how this be done in a short time, but we still could get some clues:

in [jest/packages/jest-runtime/src/cli/index.js](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/69c11a0c8192e643f4aa4c0aa79ce09cdd1ab155/packages/jest-runtime/src/cli/index.js)

```
...
import Runtime from '../';  // --->  jest/packages/jest-runtime/src/index.js

export function run(...) {
   ...
   Runtime.createContext(
       ...
   ).then(
       const runtime = new Runtime(config, environment, hasteMap.resolver);
       runtime.requireModule(filePath);
       ...
   )
}
```

`Runtime` is a critical class defined in

[jest/packages/jest-runtime/src/index.js](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/69c11a0c8192e643f4aa4c0aa79ce09cdd1ab155/packages/jest-runtime/src/index.js)

```
...

import Resolver from 'jest-resolve';

...

import ScriptTransformer from './script_transformer';

...

requireModule() {
    _execModule(...)
}

...

_execModule() {
    ...

    this._createRequireImplementation(

    ...

    this._createJestObjectFor(...)
}
```

Many critical works here, require module, detect the environment config, has `Resolver` to find the module id, to detect what kind of the module, should it be mocked, return `jestObject`, wrap all to our sandbox for testing.

Here is its core to do [mock](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/84b17fb59c1d9fd7f964b5f2bfd9d7e2b898f89a/packages/jest-mock)